# python Function returns incorrect result with @cache decorator

Tags: python

Description:
I have a Python function that uses the @cache decorator from the functools module to cache its results for faster execution. The function takes a 2D grid of integers as input and computes the sum of integers in a connected component of the grid. However, when I use the @cache decorator, the function returns an incorrect result that is greater than the actual sum.

I want to know why using the @cache decorator causes the function to produce incorrect results, and how I can fix the issue while still using caching to speed up the function execution.

```
class Solution:
    def findMax(self, grid: list[list[int]]) -> int:
        n = len(grid)
        m=len(grid[0])
        ans = 0
        flag = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]

        def DFS(i, j):
            if i<0 or i>n-1 or j<0 or j>m-1 or flag[i][j]==1 or grid[i][j]==0:
                return 0
            x = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1]]
            k = grid[i][j]
            flag[i][j] = 1
            for p in x:
                k += DFS(i + p[0], j +p[1])
            return k

        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                if flag[i][j] == 0 and grid[i][j] != 0:
                    ans = max(ans, DFS(i, j))
        return ans


a=Solution()
print(a.findMax([[8,6],[2,6]]))#ans is 22
```

this is wrong answer

```
from  functools import  cache

class Solution:
    def findMax(self, grid: list[list[int]]) -> int:
        n = len(grid)
        m=len(grid[0])
        ans = 0
        flag = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
        @cache
        def DFS(i, j):
            if i<0 or i>n-1 or j<0 or j>m-1 or flag[i][j]==1 or grid[i][j]==0:
                return 0
            x = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1]]
            k = grid[i][j]
            flag[i][j] = 1
            for p in x:
                k += DFS(i + p[0], j +p[1])
            return k

        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                if flag[i][j] == 0 and grid[i][j] != 0:
                    ans = max(ans, DFS(i, j))
        return ans


a=Solution()
print(a.findMax([[8,6],[2,6]]))# wrong ans is 28
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? How is the cache supposed to help?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your cached function:

```
if i<0 or i>n-1 or j<0 or j>m-1 or flag[i][j]==1 or grid[i][j]==0:
```

This condition changes here:

```
flag[i][j] = 1
```

therefore, the answer is not consistent for the same `i` and `j` (it changes over time), and you cannot use `cache`.

This is an example of why it is generally good practice to only reference function arguments within a function (rather than variables defined outside of the function's scope).